# Every second message is passing by RabbitMQ, should pass each

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to run some examples from Josh Long presentation. I cut out some stuff which I don't need right now as I want to evaluate the Spring Cloud Stream over the RabbitMQ.

Unfortunately whenever I publish something with my publisher, every second message is coming to my consumer. I afraid that there is some additional consumer hidden on my PC (not killed thread or smth) - so I restarted the PC. I also created separate vhost to be sure it is only my, and again the every second message was coming to the consumer.

I have impression that something is consuming it in background, but it shouldn't. In case when I run few more publishers producing data, the output on the consumer may start to look better - like some load balancing is involved there.

So, the question is - how does should like the minimal version of publisher-consumer application, where one is publishing message every one second to the channel using Spring Cloud Stream?

Consumer:

```
@EnableBinding(ServerChannels.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReservationServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow inboundReservationFlow(ServerChannels channels) {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(channels.input())
            .handle((GenericHandler<String>) (reservationName, headers) -> {
              System.out.println(reservationName);
              return null;
            })
            .get();
  }
}

@Component
class StreamListenerComponent {

  @StreamListener("input")
  public void on(String reservationName) {
  }
}

interface ServerChannels {

  @Input
  SubscribableChannel input();

}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
class Reservation {

  public Reservation(String reservationName) {
    this.reservationName = reservationName;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String reservationName; // reservation_name
}
```

Publisher:

```
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableBinding(DeviceChannels.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class VehicleClientApplication {

  private final EventWriter eventWriter;
  private final int randomNum;
  private int counter;

  VehicleClientApplication(EventWriter eventWriter) {
    this.eventWriter = eventWriter;
    Random rn = new Random();
    int range = 10;
    randomNum = rn.nextInt(range) + 10;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VehicleClientApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50)
  public void checkRecords() {
    this.eventWriter
            .write(randomNum + " " + counter);
    System.out.println(counter);
    counter++;

  }
}

interface DeviceChannels {

  String OUTPUT = "output";

  @Output(OUTPUT)
  MessageChannel output();

}

@MessagingGateway
interface EventWriter {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = DeviceChannels.OUTPUT)
  void write(String rn);
}
```

Input:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
```

Output:

```
19 1
19 3
19 5
19 7
19 9
19 11
19 13
19 15
19 17
19 19
19 21
19 23
19 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 consumers on the `input` channel

```
@StreamListener("input")
public void on(String reservationName) {
}
```

and

```
 return IntegrationFlows
        .from(channels.input())
```

Add a `System.out` to the stream listener and you will see.

Comment: Sweet lord... so the theory about load balancing and consuming in background was proper. It works now, no comment.

Comment: Yes; the default behavior on a `DirectChannel` is round-robin distribution to consumers.

Comment: Ok, so in general it covers all my needs. I know, I'm going to be off topic now, but I asked some question softwareengineering stack exchange, but I didn't get any satisfying answer there. Are you able to give me a hint, what I should look on if: I need to broadcast some message to the consumers and the message has to be persistant, that whenever the consumer appear it will consume it; I need to publish some data to specific consumer, which was never earlier connected, and I can not set it's `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` in application.properties?

Comment: Probably better to use Kafka for that since new consumers can start consuming from the beginning of the topic - as long as not too much time has elapsed (a week by default, IIRC). There's not really a way to do that with RabbitMQ. You should really start a new question for this though.

Comment: OK, I went with some reading through Kafka and it seems better to the what I need. But, still one use case is open for me - I put my question here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358513/how-can-i-handle-multi-producer-to-single-consumer-in-kafka